# Is second harmonic generation a special case of high harmonic generation?

Tags: optics, terminology, non-linear-optics, harmonics

That might be a strange question, but while I was researching for these topics, I never found an explicit statement that would answer that question. (That might be because of the different applications or something similar.)

By HHG I mean a process in which many photons are combined into one photon via virtual levels under conservation of energy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By HHG I mean a process in which many photons are combined into one photon via virtual levels under conservation of energy.

This is pretty close to a completely misleading mischaracterization of the use of the term HHG in the literature.

The term High-Harmonic Generation (as explained fairly well in e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_harmonic_generation) and [RP-Photonics](https://www.rp-photonics.com/high_harmonic_generation.html), as well as in [this review](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.81.163) and [this one](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys620)) is reserved for a non-perturbative process in strong laser fields for which there are no known functioning "virtual levels" explanations; instead, its explanation relies on a semiclassical three-step model in which the electron is ionized (a), propagates in the driving field (b,c) and emits high-frequency radiation upon recolliding with its parent ion (d):

> [image]
>
> Image source: Corkum & Krausz, [*Nature Phys.* **3**, 381 (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys620).

---

Second-harmonic generation, on the other hand, *does* admit a perturbation-theory explanation, and it occurs at vastly lower intensities. Since both of those are incompatible with the core characteristics of HHG, there's really no sense in which you can say that second-harmonic generation is a special case of HHG.

On the other hand, leaving aside your incorrect use of terminology, from your description of the larger category that you're interested in,

> a process in which many photons are combined into one photon via virtual levels under conservation of energy,

it sounds like the key term you're looking for is [**parametric process**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_process_(optics)), which is a descriptor of nonlinear optical phenomena that encompasses all types of nonlinear optical harmonic generation, whether it be second-harmonic generation, (perturbative) third-harmonic generation, or full-blown non-perturbative HHG.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right: the process of 2nd harmonic generation (frequency doubling) also typically produces 3rd harmonics too.  You can think of it in terms of the Fourier transform of $\sin(\omega t)$ vs the Fourier transform of $\sin(\omega t)^{1+k}$, where $k$ is any value larger than $0$.  There are [3rd harmonic lasers](https://www.spectra-physics.com/assets/client_files/files/documents/datasheets/THG%20Data%20Sheet.pdf).